# How to Prevent Vuejs transition on Page Load in NuxtJS app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, css-transitions

Got a simple problem.

I have a nuxt layout file that has a sidebar that needs to be hidden with a button click.

The button and everything works but it transitions everytime a page load occurs.

Here's the code in question:
from template and style section:

```
<transition name="sidebar">
    <Sidebar v-show="showSidebar"/>                       
</transition>

.sidebar-leave-active,
.sidebar-enter-active {
  transition: .3s;
}
.sidebar-enter {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
.sidebar-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Comment: add the transition based on a condition, e.g. is `isTransition: false` and in mounted hook set `isTransition = true` and in your condition `:name="isTransition ? 'sidebar' : ''"`.

Comment: Tried a couple different variations of what you said and it didn't seem to work. Adding the transition based on a condition either disables the transition or hides the sidebar

Comment: Ended up adding a javascript before-enter hook to the transition that checks for mounted being ran already before allow the transition.
Couldn't have done it without your help thought, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a javascript before-enter hook to the transition that checks for the mounted hook being ran before allowing the transition.

```
<transition v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter" :name="(allowTransition) ? 'sidebar' : ''">
    <Sidebar v-show="showSidebar"/>                       
</transition>

data() {
    return {
      showSidebar: true, 
      isMounted: false,
      allowTransition: false    
    }    
  },
  methods : {
    beforeEnter(){      
      this.allowTransition = (this.isMounted) ? this.isMounted : !this.isMounted;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.isMounted = true;
  }
```